# Grub2 working, but not visible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

I just did a fresh dual boot installation of Windows 10 along with Ubuntu 20.4 LTS. Grub2 seems to be working fine, but simply isn't showing up. Instead, it just states "booting in insecure mode" or something of that sort.

I know that grub2 is working because if I immediately press enter, it boots in Windows (just as I customized it with Grub Customizer) and if a reboot and then on the same screen I press down and then enter, it boots in Ubuntu, just as desired.

So, everything works, except I can't see the menu. I've reinstalled Ubuntu, tried reinstalling just grub (can't figure that out). Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like something you did with GRUB customizer. From your description, it's behaving as you programmed it. Are you sure that anything is actually wrong? IMO customizing GRUB doesn't provide any tangible benefits and you risk bugging out your boot.

Comment: You may have problems with the graphics. Disable the graphical terminal like this: Remove the `#` character from the relevant line: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and make the line into `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`; Save the file, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, I fixed the tag.

Comment: @Nmath It was a problem before I used customizer. I was hoping that customizer would fix it, but nothing changed. Customizer even has an option to toggle visibility at start up, and it was on by default.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit `/etc/default/grub` (as superuser) and add
`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`. You can also play with `GRUB_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to suit your needs.

NB: After editing this file, you MUST run `update-grub` (also as root). In a terminal, type `sudo update-grub` to do so.

Good luck :)